# Error al pasar una variable php que contiene html

Tags: php, html

tengo el siguiente inconveniente, a modo prueba solo tengo estas líneas de código. Tengo un script php que según diferentes validaciones genera una salida HTMLa través de una variable, pero luego cuando quiero pasarla a un input hiiden, se muestra la variable como texto plano y creo que se debe al uso de comillas doble. Como puedo solucionar esto ?

```
  <?php
    $HTML = '   <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <p><strong>ORDEN DE COMPRA N° : </strong>123450 MARCADA EN SISTEMA CON EL ESTADO DE <strong>Pendiente</strong></p>
                        <h4>ESTE ESTADO SE DEBE AL SIGUIENTE MOTIVO</h4>
                        <p><i>•</i>SE A ABORTADO EL PROCESO DE PAGO POR EL USUARIO DESDE EL PORTAL DE TRANSBANK</p>
                    </div>
                </div>';
    ?>
    <form action="../../../portal/comprar-creditos/detalle/" method="POST" name="formPrueba">
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $HTML;?>" name="respuesta">
    </form>
```

Entonces si yo entro al navegador se imprime la variable, lo cual no debería ocurrir, agradezco sus comentarios

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El problema parece ser que el navegador está interpretando las etiquetas y al leer `<div>` cierra la del input. Si es eso creo que podría solucionarse así: `value="<?= htmlspecialchars ($HTML); ?>"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utiliza comillas simples en lugar de dobles asi:

```html
hola
<input type ="hidden" value='"adios"'>
```